# Altium DRC to catch via on plane split

Tags: altium, drc

I had a recent design flagged from the PCB house because of a via that almost didn't connect to the power plane it should have, due to its placement on a split line (see below).

I want to add a design rule to catch this type of potential problem in the future, but I can't figure out how to do that. I've tried using the "Incomplete connections" and "MinimumAnnularRing" rules, but neither one is flagging this.

Is there a design rule in Altium that will catch when most of a via's copper is masked off due to a split line?

[image]

Comment: I have never seen a rule like that. When I have dealt with inner layer vias, it seems Altium is satisfied with any sort of connection. Might be worth checking with Altium tech or Altium forums.

Comment: I don’t know the answer, but just as a vague idea, you could try to do it with some kind of separation rule from copper belonging to other nets. Something like this: If BelongsToVia and OnPowerPlane and MinDistanceToOtherNet < X mm.